# HTML or PHP code - search box by serial number

Tags: search

EDIT: It would be easier to say what I'm really hoping to achieve. I have several racks with electrical equipment. Whenever somethnig fails I get an error with a serial number which I have to look in printed manuals. I was hoping to make this digital with easy search so I input a serial number and I get a search result with a text that will point me to whick rack has a problem.

The serial number looks like N  AAA  N  N  AA  NNN

Where:
N   Area 1 or Area 2
AAA North or South
N   0 Common
    2 Aux
    3 Sig
N   1 Left
    2 Right
So I'm hoping my search result will point me to Area, Cardinal direction and the other things to avoid searching huge manuals.

Hope I explained well,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with " it will point me to the exact location of what I'm searching"?

What should the result on the GUI look like?

Comment: Edited my post, hope you can understand now. Thank you.

Comment: So you want as result a description of a location as string? like: object is placed in area one in the north blablabla

Answer (score 0):

Okay I understand.

```html
$serialNumber = "NAAANNAANNN"  //get this from a inputfield or something like this

//You can use the substring function and then simply work with key=>value arrays

$area = substr($serialNumber, 0, 1); // gives you the first number
$direction = substr($serialNumber, 1, 3); // would return in this case AAA
$someName = substr($serialNumber, 4, 1);//make this for every key in your serial

//make an array like this for every key in your serial
$array = array(
    "0"    => "common",
    "1"  => "aux",
    "3"  => "sig"
);

//now you can simply use your values stored in your variables

echo($array[$someName]);
```

I hope you understand what I tried to explain.